# Bind9 fails loading from master file because it adds a ".com" to the file they're searching

Tags: dns, bind

I'm having an odd problem that I'm not sure how to explain either here or to google.

On the named.conf.local I have declared as "site1.edu.ve" but I get this error

zone site1.ve/IN: loading from master file /etc/bind/zones/db.site1.ve.com failed: file not found

the ".ve" should be the end, but bind keeps looking for a .com file that doesn't exist

EDIT 1: Adding some of the config files

**named.conf**

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

**named.conf.local**

```
zone "rect.ucv.edu.ve" {
        type primary;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.rect.ucv.edu.ve";
        allow-transfer { 190.169.31.195; };
};

zone "169.190.in-addr.arpa" {
        type primary;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.190.169";
        allow-transfer { 190.169.31.195; };
};
```

Comment: You need to look at the configurations.  *Share* your configurations here as well for your system min order for us to debug it.  The only time stuff like this happens is when your config is wrong/brokenk

Comment: `bind` certainly does not add anything to any name, it just uses what you specify in configuration. Did you run `named-checkconf` to check for everything? Are you sure you don't have multiple bind installs or configuration files? Your error message, even without the `.com` in file name, does not match any of your 2 zone names in configuration snippet provided, or filenames.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yes, that's the odd thing, I ran a grep nr 'edu.ve.' . on the folder /etc/bind and there's not a single line that ends with .com

Comment: If you use grep you might instead wish to search which text files has `db.site1.ve.com` in it, as it will probably be the configuration file bind is using despite which one you think it does. If you don't want to search too long and are ok with restarting from scratch, just purge the package, and start again from 0. Not very satisfactory globally, but if the goal is to have something working as quickly as possible this might be fastest path.